# Can I push notifications to Facebook?

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api

I am building a web application using node.js and express.js. I do also use passport.js to authenticate users with Facebook login. I would like to push certain events from my app to the user, so that the user receives a notification at facebook. I am not sure if this is possible or not, is it?

I have tried this, but did not get it to work: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications

I got this error: (#200) Only web canvas apps can send app notifications when trying the endpoint in Postman.

My application do just use the login from facebook, otherwise, it has no other interaction with facebook at the moment.

Comment: what´s unclear about the error message? app notifications are not for external websites, but only for apps on facebook.com, as you can read in the docs.

Comment: To clarify, I would like to know if there is any other way to access this functionality? Or is it just not possible.

Comment: no, there is no other way. facebook is not a notification center for external website.